# Why can't I use CppUnitLite test CHECK_DOUBLES_EQUAL

Tags: c++, cppunit

I'm a novice programmer taking a c++ class.

The assignment is to write a double using stringstream, then check it using one of the macros in CppUnitLite. I want to use CHECK_DOUBLES_EQUAL to check the double in my write operation, but intellisense in VS says it wont' work. In the sample below, I've left what does work, a simple CHECK_EQUAL. This isn't good enough. I need to use CHECK_DOUBLES_EQUAL for floating point.

I've tried CHECK_DOUBLES_EQUAL(dvalue, svalue, 0.1) but that won't work. I've also tried using the actual value for expected, but that doesn't work either.

CHECK_DOUBLES_EQUAL does work for the read operation (second example), but I can't get it to work in the first.

Why is this? What am I doing wrong?

```
TEST(writeDouble, stringStream)
{
    std::stringstream sValue;
    double dvalue =34.9;
    sValue << dvalue;
    if (!sValue)
    {
        CHECK_FAIL("conversion failed");
    }
    CHECK_EQUAL("34.9", sValue.str());  
}

TEST(readDouble, stringStream)
{
    std::stringstream sValue("34.9");
    double dvalue;
    sValue >> dvalue;
    if (!sValue)
    {
        CHECK_FAIL("conversion failed");
    }
    CHECK_DOUBLES_EQUAL(34.9, dvalue, 0.1);
}
```

Comment: Can you also post the code for CHECK_DOUBLES_EQUAL?

Comment: What is `CHECK_DOUBLE_EQUAL`?

Comment: `CHECK_DOUBLES_EQUAL` is not standard C++ and without showing us what it does, or what you mean by "can't get it to work" there's unfortunately not a lot we can do to help you.

Comment: Thanks guys. I didn't realize this wasn't such a good question. CHECK_DOUBLES_EQUAL is from CppUnitLIte which I added to my project, but I am not really sure where to get the code for it.

Comment: I've tried to spruce up the question a little. Damn, someone gave me a downvote. So harsh! :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that in your write operation, you aren't trying to compare against a double: You're trying to compare against a STRING. C++ is a statically typed language and won't compare a string to a double.

The code you're using with `CHECK_EQUAL("34.9", sValue.str());` would appear to be the correct code to use to ensure that the `stringstream` correctly interpreted the input double value.

Comment: @Mark Ransom the OP explicitly states that `CHECK_DOUBLES_EQUAL` works great in the second example (the one with `sValue >> dvalue`)

Comment: Thanks, in that case I really don't know what the question is then. I'll delete my comment.